# ggplot geom_bar shows wrong scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm stuck. I am trying to make a barplot using ggplot:

```
ggplot(data_ocena, aes(x=grupa, y=ocena, fill=ocena)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("częstość występowania poszczególnych ocen na kolokwium")
```

results in:

[image]

how to deal with that? variable ocena is factor, group is factor also.

Comment: Maybe add a more famous tag; Python or R for example (Depending on what it relates to) it will be more visible that way.

Comment: Can you supply a subset of your data? And can you clarify what it is you're expecting to see?

Comment: It looks like your `y` variable is a character/factor instead of numeric.

Comment: yeah, it was it. Needed to convert y to numeric and and revert it to factor when calling fill. Thx! :*